# How to show the result of condition in Visual Studio debugging?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

How can I let me show the result of a condition in visual studio while debugging through? Let's say my code looks like:

```
If a > b andalso c > b andalso d < y then
```

If i step through I cannot see which of the three conditions are false. Is there a way to be able to?

Comment: How about copy the values of a,b,c,... to "Watch" window. Use drag and drop.

Comment: This might work in this case but if you got more complex conditions which are using arrays or calls functions it is getting difficult and time consuming to understand which of these conditions have failed. I have hoped there would be a tooltip or similar showing me the result of each condition.

Comment: Thats why, we always write the code as simple as possible, so that everybody can read the code without any difficulties. And always avoiding Quick and Dirty code.

Comment: In the Watch window add these expressions: `a > b`, `c > b` and `d < y`. You might also want to add expression `a > b && c > b && d < y`. If you have more complex expressions, just add them to Watch window.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the debugconsole to write the results like this:

```
bool ab = a > b;
bool cb = c > b;
bool dy = d < y;

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("a > b = " + ab + ", "c > b = " cb + ", d < y = " + dy");
if (ab && cd && dy)
{
  //Your code here
}
```

The 3 results are shown on the debugconsole like

> a > b = true, c > b = false, d < y = true

Optional you could add a fourth boolean like

```
bool result = ab && cd && dy;
```

and print it also on the console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the immediate window and copy paste single conditions or anything else you like. This way you don't need to change your code.

Comment: Your point about not needing to change the code is very important. Debugging should not interfere with the program itself. The Immediate and Watch windows are very similar. One advantage of the Watch window is that the expressions there are automatically updated each time execution breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a code in away which is the best for debugging it will horrible way of coding, e.g. the best way to rewrite the above for debugging as follows:

```
bool isValid = false;

isValid = isValid && a > b
isValid = isValid && c > b
isValid = isValid && d < y
```

Unless there is a certain logic in your program to find which part is failing... this way is nonsense, it just better if you add each part to the watch and validate it, overall debugging is not the purpose of code writing.

Comment: You would be better to do: `bool condOne = a > b;  bool condTwo = c > b;  bool condThree = d < y;  if (condOne && condTwo && condThree) { ... }` Similar effect, but far more readable.

Comment: @CodyGray you r right, but all lead to the same result ... bad code ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I were having an issue with the code I would rewrite it like this so that it was clear and easy to debug.

```
    Dim aGTb As Boolean = a > b
    Dim cGTb As Boolean = c > b
    Dim dLTy As Boolean = d < y

    If aGTb AndAlso cGTb AndAlso dLTy Then

    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use `System.Diagnostics`
and use `Debugger.Break()` to stop debugger at this line and see the Debugger Output,
Like this sample code:

in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Test
{
    static volatile int a = a, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, y = 5;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        Debug.WriteLine("a > b:{0}", a > b);
        Debug.WriteLine("c > b:{0}", c > b);
        Debug.WriteLine("d < y:{0}", d < y);
        Debug.WriteLine("a > b && c > b && d < y:{0}", a > b && c > b && d < y);
        if (a > b && c > b && d < y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("...");
        }
    }
}
```

or in VB:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim a As Integer = 1, b As Integer = 2, c As Integer = 3, d As Integer = 4, y As Integer = 5

        Debugger.Break()
        Debug.WriteLine("a > b:{0}", a > b)
        Debug.WriteLine("c > b:{0}", c > b)
        Debug.WriteLine("d < y:{0}", d < y)
        Debug.WriteLine("a > b && c > b && d < y:{0}", a > b AndAlso c > b AndAlso d < y)
        If a > b AndAlso c > b AndAlso d < y Then
            Console.WriteLine("...")
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

i hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
if(a>b)
{
   if(c>b)
   {
      if(d<y)
      {
          /* Your code here */
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.